# Why a dynamic button does not respect the height in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, dynamic

In the simplified example below in `Kotlin` in `Android Studio` I use a `constraint layout` in `XML` empty

After I've created dynamically a `textview` with a background image and then I've created a `button` with same size with a centralized text. I also have programmed the constraints in relation to the button, text and the parent (constraint layout).

The display in my cell phone stubbornly stretches the button to occupy the bottom half of the screen.

What did I do wrong?

My code of my unique activity (except the imports) is

```
var idGlob:Int = 100
fun incId():Int {
   idGlob++
   return idGlob  
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var newView:ImageView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val newText: TextView = TextView(this)
        myLayout.addView(newText)
        newText.setText("XO")
        newText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        newText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,28F);
        newText.layoutParams.height = 200
        newText.layoutParams.width = 400
                  // XML Vector Image from a SVG file
        newText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_square) 
        newText.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        newText.id = incId()  // Custom function to generate unique ID
        val c = ConstraintSet()
        c.clone(myLayout)    
        c.connect(newText.id,ConstraintSet.START,   
              ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.START,0)
        c.connect(newText.id,ConstraintSet.END,
              ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.END,0)
        c.connect(newText.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,
              ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.TOP,0)       
        c.connect(newText.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
              ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0)
        val newBut: Button  = Button(this)
        myLayout.addView(newBut)
        newBut.height = 200  // I also tried newBut.layoutParams.height
        newBut.width = 400   // I also tried newBut.layoutParams.width
        newBut.id = incId() // Custom function to generate unique ID
        newBut.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA)
        newBut.text = "CENTER"
        newBut.textAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER
        c.connect(newBut.id,ConstraintSet.START,
            newText.id,ConstraintSet.START,0)
        c.connect(newBut.id,ConstraintSet.END,
            newText.id,ConstraintSet.END,0)
        c.connect(newBut.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,   // If I remove this line
            newText.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0)
        c.connect(newBut.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, // or this one(see PS3)
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0)
        c.applyTo(myLayout)

    }
}
```

The result in Cell Phone is

[image: Cell phone display<code>enter code here</code>]

**UPDATE**: In order to show what is not working is the dynamic equivalent of the static solution, the static solution with the same values works perfectly:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="400px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:text="XO"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_square"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:id="@+id/textView"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Center"
            android:layout_width="400px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**PS 1**: My layout uses `Constraint Layout`. So I've tried

```
newBut.setLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(400, 200))
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work either!

**PS 2**: I've also tried

```
newBut.maxHeight = 200
```

Nothing changes.

**PS 3**: If I remove one of two final `connect` calls from code (top or bottom from button), the  `Center button` disappears!

**PS 4**: If I remove all `connect` calls from `Center button` and add

```
newBut.y = 1200F
newBut.x = 300F
```

The size works like a charm, but I need to use coordinates and not constraints.

Comment: That is not the way to set width and height for you button. You should be using Layout parms I believe

Comment: My layout uses `Constraint Layout`. So I've tried `newBut.setLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(400, 200))`, but it didn't work either!

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Comment: I will remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here your problem in line `c.connect(newBut.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, // or this one(see PS3)
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0)` you were aligning button constraint bottom to parent that's why it is stretching instead use 
     val newText: TextView = TextView(this)

```
    myLayout.addView(newText)
    newText.setText("XO")
    newText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    newText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,28F);
    newText.layoutParams.height = 200
    newText.layoutParams.width = 400
    // XML Vector Image from a SVG file
    newText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_square)
    newText.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    newText.id = incId()  // Custom function to generate unique ID
    val c = ConstraintSet()
    c.clone(myLayout)
    c.connect(newText.id,ConstraintSet.START,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.START,0)
    c.connect(newText.id,ConstraintSet.END,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.END,0)
    c.connect(newText.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.TOP,0)
    c.connect(newText.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0)
    val newBut: Button  = Button(this)
    myLayout.addView(newBut)
    newBut.height = 200  // I also tried newBut.layoutParams.height
    newBut.width = 400   // I also tried newBut.layoutParams.width
    newBut.id = incId() // Custom function to generate unique ID
    newBut.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
    newBut.text = "CENTER"
    newBut.textAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER

    c.connect(newBut.id,ConstraintSet.START,
            newText.id,ConstraintSet.START,0)
    c.connect(newBut.id,ConstraintSet.END,
            newText.id,ConstraintSet.END,0)
    c.connect(newBut.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,   // If I remove this line
            newText.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0)
    c.constrainHeight(newBut.id,200) ***// set button height here***
 /*   c.connect(newBut.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, // or this one(see PS3)
            newBut.id,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0)*/
    c.applyTo(myLayout)
```

Comment: It's funny, because my code it works statically (XML), but not dinamically. However, your solution works! It's just to add `c.constrainHeight(newBut.id,200)` in my code. No `connect` change in my code.   I don't know why! If I replace your line for `newBut.height  = 200`, it fails and stretch the rectangle again.